# Spring, JPA, Hibernate 3 vs 4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm using Spring (3.2.4.RELEASE) and Hibernate (4.2.8.Final) in my project, and using JPA configuration.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    ...
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
       <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
          ...
       </bean>
    </property>
 </bean>
 <bean id="transactionManager"
       class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
     <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
 </bean>
```

And I use hibernate optimistic locking versioning mechanisms like below.

```
@Entity
public class Entity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Version
    @Generated(GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
    private int version;
}
```

My question is when I update Entity with wrong version, why it's throw

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException`

not

`org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` ?

Comment: Actually both are strange... I would expect a `JpaOptimisticLockingFailureException` or `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`. The specific `HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException` should be thrown when using hibernate not jpa. You don't by accident have an explicitly configured `HibernateExceptionTranslator` in your context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE contains packages for both org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.* and org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.*.

So even if you have hibernate-4.2.8.Final.jar in your project lib when you are using spring data jpa, on any kind of wrong DB operation to convert all checked exceptions to unchecked(runtime) hibernate exceptions HibernateExceptionTranslator is used from org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator.

Make sure you have used org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateExceptionTranslator in your bean configuration xml file if you want it to use 3.0.